# How can I replace a start a Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO) activity with org.jetbrains.anko.startActivity?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have read the artical https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Intents

The Code A is to  open a send email activity,  I hope to replace it with org.jetbrains.anko.startActivity, how can I do? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
fun sendFeedbackByEmail(mContext: Context) {
    val data = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
    data.data = Uri.parse("mailto:" + mContext.getString(R.string.FeedbackEmailAddress))
    data.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mContext.getString(R.string.FeedbackEmailSubject))
    data.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mContext.getString(R.string.FeedbackEmailFirstContent))
    mContext.startActivity(data)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not try to replace with the startActivity function. There is function available in Anko. It goes like this

```
email(email, [subject], [text])
```

Arguments in square brackets `([])` are optional. Methods return true if the intent was sent.

You can call it like

```
email("youremail@yourdomain.com","Your Subject","Your Text")
```

Right now  they don't have feature where you can send same email to multiple email id. You have to make another call.

Anki is achieving is by writing extension over `Context` and `Fragment` classes. So this function is available for both Activity and Function

Comment: Thanks! how can I write code if I use org.jetbrains.anko.startActivity?

Comment: Why you want to use startActivity from Anko when you have extension function available?